# Как заставить подставлять переменную из БД MySQL в цикле? использую PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpquery

Всем доброго времени! Скажу сразу, мой опыт программирования является крайне скудным. Появилось свободное время, и я решил подтянуть свои знания, путем написания парсера сайта(ов) с возможностью записи всех данных в БД MySQL. На текущий момент, я получил все ссылки с сайта на каталоги, которые представляют для меня ценность и записал их в БД. На текущем шаге, мне необходимо заставить данный скрипт считать строку с БД и вставить ее в выполняемый скрипт. после завершения цикла(функции), необходимо прочитать следующую строку в БД и вернуть результат выполнения. Ткните лицом пожалуйста, где мои ошибки, что я делаю не так и в какую сторону смотреть. Если, кто-то предложит работающий вариант, буду крайне благодарен.
Код:

```
// Ставим игнорирование SSL сертификата при вызове функции file_get_contents($url);
$arrContextOptions = array(
    "ssl" => array(
        "verify_peer" => false,
        "verify_peer_name" => false,
    ),
);
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
// Эмулируем браузер
header('Content-Type: text/html; utf-8; charset=UTF-8');
// Пoдключаем библиотеку phpQuery
require 'phpQuery.php';
// Соединение с сервером БД
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Не удалось подключиться к MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
// Узнаем кодировку и принудительно назначаем UTF-8
printf("Изначальная кодировка: %s\n", $mysqli->character_set_name());
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
// Запускаем парсер страниц
function parser($url)
{
    for ($k = 0; $k <= 2; $k++) {
        $file = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions)); //Получаем страницу
        $file = iconv('windows-1251', 'utf-8', $file); // конвертируем кодировку
        $doc  = phpQuery::newDocument($file); // Создаем DOM документ
        foreach ($doc->find('#container') as $data) {
            // Получаем данные контейнера 
            $data      = $doc->find('#container');
            $part_name = $data->find('div:eq(3)')->text();
            $part_code = $data->find('div:eq(4)')->text();
            //Получаем таблицу с остатками и ценами
            $data_part = $data->find('div.catalog__stock_tovar_list');
            //Ищем остаток и цену.
            $part_price    = $data_part->find('tr:eq(1) td:eq(2)')->text();
            $part_quantity = $data_part->find('tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)')->text();
            // записываем полученные данные в таблицу ИСПРАВИТЬ
            // $mysqli->real_query("INSERT INTO href(link, name) VALUES ('$url', '$data')");
            echo '$part_name';
            phpQuery::unloadDocuments();
            gc_collect_cycles();
        }
    }
    $query = "SELECT Name FROM href ORDER BY Name";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

        /* Переход к строке №*/
        $result->data_seek($k);
        /* Получение строки */
        $url = $result->fetch_row();
    }
}

parser($url);
```

Быть может, сама постановка не совсем верна, не могу понять в какую сторону копать.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT name FROM href ORDER BY Name");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    parser($row['name']);
}
```